# C++ program gets undefined reference to a dynamic C library during linking

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker

I've created a dynamic networking library in C. When I try to link it in my C++ program I get an undefined reference the first time I call one of my functions in the library. What I can't understand is that I created a little test program in C that uses the library and it links just fine.

Could someone help with my problem? Here are the steps I've taken to create my library and link it.

Library creation:

- Code my library
- Compile with the line: gcc -c -fPIC -g -Wall ./libnet.c
- Link my library object file and create the shared object file with the line: gcc -shared -o libnet.so -g -Wall ./libnet.o

Move my library to the appropriate folders and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

- I copy my library to two directories. One directory is the test C program that links properly and one is the C++ program that doesn't link properly.
- I set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to both the directories that use the library

Compile and link my program:

- Code my program
- Compile all my .cpp files with the line: g++ -c -g -Wall ./
- Link together all my object files and the shared library to create my program with the line: g++ -o  -g -Wall -L./ -lnet

Here is the make file that I use. Maybe I have something wrong in here?

> PPFLAGS =    -g -Wall
>
> TARGET =    msgfrwdserver
>
> OBJS =     msgfrwdserver.o
>   msgfrwdhelper.o msgfrwd.o climsgfrwd.o
>
> LIBS =      libnet.so
>
> CPPLP =
>       -L/usr/home/chris/development/legends/servers/monitor
>   -L/usr/home/chris/development/legends/servers/msgfrwd
>
> CPPFILES =   ./msgfrwdserver.cpp
>   ./msgfrwdhelper.cpp
>   ./classes/msgfrwd.cpp
>   ./classes/climsgfrwd.cpp
>
> CPPIP =     -I./classes
>   -I/usr/home/chris/development/legends/libnet
>
> all: ${OBJS} ${TARGET}
>
> ${TARGET}: ${OBJS} ${LIBS}
>
> g++ -o
>   ${TARGET} ${PPFLAGS} -L./ -lnet
>   ${CPPIP} ${OBJS}
>
> msgfrwdserver.o: ./msgfrwdserver.cpp
>
> g++ -c ${PPFLAGS} ${CPPIP}
>   ./msgfrwdserver.cpp
>
> msgfrwdhelper.o:
>   ./msgfrwdhelper.cpp
>
> g++ -c ${PPFLAGS}
>   ./msgfrwdhelper.cpp
>
> msgfrwd.o:
>   ./classes/msgfrwd.cpp
>
> g++ -c
>   ${PPFLAGS} ./classes/msgfrwd.cpp
>
> climsgfrwd.o: ./classes/climsgfrwd.cpp
>
> g++ -c ${PPFLAGS} ${CPPIP}
>   ./classes/climsgfrwd.cpp
>
> clean:  rm
>   -rf ${TARGET} *.o *~ *.core ./classes/*~

I really have no idea what the problem could be. Any help would be much appreciated. Do I have to do something differently to get a C library to work with a C++ program?

Sorry that the make file is messy. I didn't exactly translate well when I tried to block quote it or say it was a code sample.

Comment: Did you think of `extern "C"`-ing the library functions in the headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C library functions must have en [**extern "C"**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) definition in order to call them from C++ to turn of name-mangeling.

```
extern "C" 
{ 
    int test();
}
```

With the extern , the the Microsoft C++ compiler will look for the symbol "**_test**", otherwise it will look for "**?test@@YAHXZ**" (The C++ name-mangeled version of int test() )

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. The link provided documentation which explained how to solve the problem. Thanks for you help.